# jQuery Resize Line of text To Fit Div Width

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am using the following script to resize a one line string to fit properly in a div box.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $( '.test' ).css( 'font-size', 0 ).each(function ( i, box2 ) {
        var width = $( box2 ).width()
        var line = $( box2 ).wrapInner( '<span style="white-space:nowrap">' ).children()[ 0 ];
        function changeFontSize( n ) {
            $( box2 ).css( 'font-size', function ( i, val ) {
                                            return parseInt( val, 10 ) + n; });
                                        })
        while ( $( line ).width() < width ) { changeFontSize( 1 ); }
        changeFontSize( -1 );
        $( box2 ).text( $( line ).text() );
    });
</script>
```

This script works perfect in Firefox, Chrome, and opera.  However in IE if the user is in compatibility mode it errors and locks up the browser.  I do not know enough about the older browsers to know what I have added that is not compatible.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: _" in compatability mode it errors"_ - Do you actually get an error message? If so, what is it? (Maybe IE is just confused at the dearth of line breaks in your code? I know I am.)

Comment: There is no error it acts as if there is a unclosed loop

Answer (score 0):

This is formatted wrong, may break in IE, its always so touchy.

```
<span style="white-space:nowrap">
```

Should be

```
<span style="white-space:nowrap;">
```